# How to create a matrix consists of submatrix

Tags: numpy

I want to create a matrix consists of some submatrix, or elements are defined by some conditions about indices.

e.g.

```py
X = np.array(
[[0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
)
```

where `i`-row and `j`-col meets conditions below

```
0 if 2k ≤ i < 2(k+1) and 2k ≤ j < 2(k+1)
1 otherwise
```

In the above condition, `k` is `0, 1, 2...` and `2` is also a parameter to change and

So, what I finally need is

```
0 if nk ≤ i < n(k+1) nk ≤ j < n(k+1)
1 otherwise
```

I think `np.ix_` is good for this demand, but it requires a loop structure (I hate loops).

Is there some nice way to generate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be utilizing the `outer` method of the `not_equal` operator like so:

```
N = 17; k = 5
np.not_equal.outer(*2*(np.arange(N)//k,)).view('u1')
# array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Very nice!